# ProGuard: Keep inner static class but rename parent class

Tags: android, proguard

I want to know if its possible to keep the name of a public static inner Class but renaming the parent classname.

My code looks like this:

```
public class MyDao extends AbstractDao {

    public static final String TABLENAME = "BOX_DOWNLOAD";

    public static class Properties {
        public final static Property ID = new Property(0, Long.class, "ID", true, "ID");
        public final static Property Name = new Property(1, String.class, "name", false, "NAME");
        public final static Property Done = new Property(2, Boolean.class, "done", false, "DONE");
        // SOME MORE CONSTANTS
    };

    // SOME CODE WHICH CAN BE OBFUSCATED

}
```

I want ProGuard to replace:
MyDao (the className)

```
the PROPERTIES' variables (ID, Name, Done)
```

I want ProGuard NOT to replace:

```
TABLENAME (variable name)
PROPERTIES (className only)
```

I tried this

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao {
  public static <fields>;
  public static class *;
}
```

But this is not working. The classNames are not obfuscated.

// EDIT
I forgot to say that there are several classes like MyDao. Eg. MyDao1, MyDao2, etc.

I want to use wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Usage > [Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions)

```
-keepclassmembers class de.greenrobot.dao.MyDao {
    String TABLENAME;
}

-keep class de.greenrobot.dao.MyDao$Properties
```

**Update:** When keeping the name "MyDao$Properties", the current version of ProGuard appears to keep the name "MyDao" as well (even if the InnerClasses attribute is not preserved). This is somewhat more conservative than strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using your method does not work for me - the classname "MyDao" is not obfuscated. I also forgot to say that I got several classes called e.g. MyDao1, MyDao2 etc. They all look like the one I descriped in my question (container TABLENAME and PROPERTIES cals). I want to use wildcards so I do not have to specify all callses.

Comment: I've tried it now and you're right. Keeping the inner class name also keeps its package names and the outer class names. In this case, keeping "MyDao$Properties" as "MyDao$Properties", but still renaming "MyDao" to something like "a" would technically be possible, but it seems only marginally useful. I probably won't be changing this behavior.

Comment: You can actually do this: -keep public class class de.greenrobot.dao.**$Properties {*;}

Answer (score 0):

I have made following scripts, which works for me.

```
-keep class my.dao.package.*$Properties {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class my.dao.package.** {
    public java.lang.String TABLENAME;    
}
```

I have used wildcard for inner classes, which worked.